# How to get a label under an underlined word in css?

Tags: css

This is the effect I am looking for

```
blahblahblah blah blah blahblahalhab foo bar.
------------           -------------
     A                       B
```

How would I get the A and B labels directly underneath the underlined words in HTML/CSS/JavaScript?

**To start:**

```
<p><span><u>text number 1</u></span> followed by <span><u>text number 2</u></span> end of sentence</p>
<p>        <span>A</span>                                  <span>B</span></p>
```

Comment: could you provide more context?

Comment: What do you have? What have you tried? And where are you stuck?

Comment: If he had the snippets he would not need our help

Comment: @mplungjan this site is called [so], not buildmycodeformeplz.com. He should try it himself, and if he's stuck ask here.

Comment: @MadaraUchiha I am aware of that. However this is so non-obvious that what he provided is a) enough to understand what to do and b) so difficult for a noob that it is not even known if CSS is enough or javascript would be needed to position. Give the user a break. I would not even know what to start with except a line with a few spans

Comment: this seems like an interesting question.  Whether it should be closed or not is up to the community.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Markup (HTML):

```
<span class="labeled">blahblahblah<span class="label">A</span></span> blah blah <span class="labeled">blahblahalhab<span class="label">B</span></span> foo bar.
```

Style (CSS):

```
span.labeled {
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: top;
}
span.labeled span.label {
    display: block;
    text-align: center;
    border-top: 1px solid black;
}
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/SxaK6/

Result:

[image]

Comment: Nice trick, doesn't have the same problem I had because of absolute positioning.

Comment: Works in Chrome on Windows 7, Fx 18 on WinXP

Comment: @mplungjan Thanks for the screenshot :)

Answer (score 1):

Another way to do it, if you just want a *visual effect* and not necessarily to have the `HTML` for 'A' and 'B' `<span>`s, would be using [`CSS3` `:before` `pseudo-element`](http://coding.smashingmagazine.com/2011/07/13/learning-to-use-the-before-and-after-pseudo-elements-in-css/):

HTML

```
<span id="a" class="labeled">blahblahblah</span> blah blah 
<span id="b" class="labeled">blahblahalhab</span> foo bar.
```

CSS

```
span.labeled {        
    border-bottom: 1px solid black;
    position: relative;
}

.labeled:before{
    margin-top: 25px;
    position: absolute;
    text-align: center;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
}
#a:before{
    content: 'A';
}
#b:before{
    content: 'B';    
}
```

DEMO: http://jsfiddle.net/cu8Q5/

Comment: Thank you! This is also a great help!

Answer (score 0):

I would add the labels *inside* the underlined elements in the markup, then reposition with CSS:

```
<span class="underlined">
   blahblahblah<span class="label">A</span>
</span> 
blah blah 
<span class="underlined">
   blahblahalhab<span class="label">B</span>
</span>
foo bar.
```

```
.underlined {
    position: relative;
    text-decoration: underline;
}

.label {
    position: absolute;
    top: 105%;
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/AyC84/

Comment: When I check your fiddle, the letters `A` and `B` overlap.

Comment: Hm, they do if there is a line break.

Comment: I have no line break but they do anyways. Firefox 18 on linux.

Comment: Chrome works if the viewport is big enough not to make two lines

Comment: Worked fine for me in Chrome. But I recommend Cobra_Fast's solution; it shouldn't have a similar problem, as it doesn't use `position: absolute`, keeping everything in flow.